# How to remove only created hour?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, datetime

I'm using Drupal 7 and Clean theme. And when created a node, show date top on node. No problem. But i want remove only hour and min. tab.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would disable the created date display under the content type settings, and then just add a new [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field whose display settings you can alter just like any other field.

The other option would be to change it by overriding [hook_tokens](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7) in your theme. Specifically, you would override `format_date($node->created, 'medium', '', NULL, $language_code);` with your custom date format.

Comment: Yes maybe but i search easily way.

Comment: Where can i put this code?

Comment: You would probably want to create a custom theme. There's a [theming guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) on Drupal.org.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to have your node show *June 12, 2012*

If that is the case, you can do this:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['submitted']) {
    $variables['submitted'] = t('Posted: !datetime', array( '!datetime' => format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', 'F j, Y')));
  }
}
```

Here's PHP documentation for date formats: http://php.net/manual/function.date.php